# Why is the highlighting on these features obscured?

Tags: leaflet, esri-leaflet, css

I have a function that highlights features when the user enters search text, and that text is found in the attributes of the given features.

The code basically works; the problem is in the display. I want the highlighting to appear clear and unbroken on top of the map, but it ends ends up partly obscured by the other layers of the map. I tried using the .bringToFront method, to no avail.

How can I get the highlighting to appear strong and clear on top of the map?

Here's the code:

```
document.getElementById('searchText').value = "";            
var searchText = document.getElementById('searchText');
var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson('').addTo(map); 

function goBtn() {
        map.removeLayer(foundFeatures);
        Zones.find().layers('0').text(searchText.value)
                .run(function(error, featureCollection, response){
                    foundFeatures = L.geoJson(featureCollection, {
                        style: function(){
                          return {
                            color: 'black',
                          weight: 5
                          };
                        }
                    }).addTo(map);       
          foundFeatures.bringToFront();
          map.fitBounds(foundFeatures.getBounds());
          });
    }
```

Here's the result:

[image: illustration]

You can see that the pieces of the feature boundaries that do NOT border another feature actually do appear unobscured, but the boundaries that are shared with another feature are greyed out.

Answer (score 1):

From the rough trimming / clipping of your coloured areas, the latter look like raster images (probably image overlays?).

In that case, `bringToFront()` will not work because it will bring your vector shape on top of other shapes, but not on top of other image overlays that are already on top of the vectors container.

You can try to have that vectors container on top by adding your image overlays before you add ANY vector shape to the map.

You could also try something like:

```js
map._panes.overlayPane.appendChild(map._pathRoot);
```

…to dynamically put the vectors container on top of any other image overlay. I have not tried it yet though.

Once that vectors container is on top, you you use `bringToFront()` to re-order your vectors one each other.

---

**EDIT:** (following the code shared through JS Bin)

Your coloured areas are built using [`L.esri.dynamicMapLayer`](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/layers/dynamic-map-layer.html), which is a special Raster Image Overlay (with refresh on map navigation and features identification service). So my above comment (original answer before edit) still applies.

Furthermore, in your JS Bin, strangely you apply `bringToFront()` on that Dynamic Map Layer (variable `Zones`), so obviously it will be on top of the vectors container, and overlay your newly added black polygons (`foundFeatures`).

Whereas in the code you shared in your question, you used `foundFeatures.bringToFront()`, which *may* work at the beginning if this is the first time some vectors are added to map (so that the vectors container is added on top of the Dynamic Map Layer), but it is pushed back as soon as you change the zoom level, because the Dynamic Map Layer is updated and added to the front.

So a simple workaround would be to:

1. Push the Dynamic Map Layer (`Zones`) to the back, so that it is behind the vectors container even when it is updated.
2. Bring the new black polygons (`foundFeatures`) to the front, exactly like you did in the question code, just to make sure it is on top (it should be already as it is just added).

```js
function goBtn() {
    map.removeLayer(geoJsonLayer);
    Zones.find().layers('0').text(searchText.value)
            .run(function(error, featureCollection, response){

                geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(featureCollection, {
                    style: { color: 'black' }
                }).addTo(map)
                //Zones.bringToFront();
                Zones.bringToBack();
                foundFeatures.bringToFront();
      });
}
```

Updated JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/nifovajena/edit?html,output

Comment: No, the colored areas (Zones) are a vector layer. The highlighted features (foundFeatures) are also vectors. Shouldn't `bringToFront()` work in that case?

Comment: Indeed, if everything is vector (shapes), `bringToFront()` should work as advertised. Which version of Leaflet do you use?

Comment: It's 0.7.3, plus the esri-leaflet library.

Comment: Any chance you could reproduce your issue in an online editing tool, e.g. on JSFiddle or Plunker?

Comment: Here it is on jsbin; will that work? I've had trouble getting it to show up in jsfiddle. [link] (http://jsbin.com/mesorapiqe/edit?html,output) To see the problem, type a word such as "germans" in the Search box and click 'Go'.

Comment: Yes jsbin is fine. I will edit the above answer.